# Generate meaningful id's for firebase documents

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app where users have to register themselves for an event. After registration, I want to provide each user with a unique id that is based on the timestamp of their registration and it should be alphanumeric that can be remembered. Please suggest a way of doing this. I have already managed to take input from the user and store it in firestore, but the auto-generated id is quite verbose and un-workable.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with IDs like this?  In general, with Firestore, document IDs don't need to contain data.  Meaningful data would be stored in fields in each document.  The IDs just need to be unique.

Comment: A timestamp can look like this *2019-12-08T15:32:40.334Z* or in Firestore like this *December 8, 2019 at 11:05:52 AM UTC-5* or in the Real Time Database... well, the RTDB doesn't store timestamps so it may be a double. What you are looking for is *alphanumeric that can be remembered* so you want the user to remember one of those or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use a client side library like shortid:

- JS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid
- Dart: https://pub.dev/packages/shortid

If you want to do things server-side, use [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) paired with the JS shortid library to add the ID into the document.